# How to specify a destination DB while exporting data frame to mssql

Tags: sql-server, r, export, rodbc

I would like to export a data frame to mssql table.I used the code below but I would like to set the destination and not only the server and table name.I have a few DBs inside the server,how can i save the table in one of them?

```
df<-read.csv(file.choose(),header = T,sep= T)
DB= odbcConnect(dsn ='R_BISRV',uid = 'XXXX', pwd = 'XXX')
sqlSave(DB, df, tablename = 'Tanya', rownames = F,append = T)
close(DB)
```

Comment: I use the RMySQL package. You specify the database name in the connection (or ideally in a my.cnf file). Other commands need to be changed slightly from those used in RODBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
Data base name should be in the `odbcDriverConnect()` and table name in the `sqlSave()`

```
channel <- odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server};server=YYY;database=YY;port=1433;
uid=XX;pwd=XXX') 
# Client systems use TCP 1433 to connect to the database engine

sqlSave(channel = channel,dat = df, rownames = TRUE, tablename = "Tanya")
```